# Bootstrap 3 Collapse bringing me to top of page and not working either

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page created using bootstrap 3. I found an example code of how to build a forum and i customized it a bit. On the bottom forum toping (critique) I want to be able to click on it and when I do it, below it, uncollapse information. For now i just have "testing" in there but later I will add html tags and style it.

What is happening now is when i click the topic it brings me to the top of the page and the "testing" appears above not below.

Here is my jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/mattmega4/kdoxsoo9/

```
      <div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a href ="index.html" class="navbar-brand">U.P.M.</a>
        <img src="assets/camera.png" class="pull-left">
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-
target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>


        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = 
"dropdown">Options<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li id=default><a  href="#">Change Theme</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>



<div class="bigpappa">
  <div class="container well">
    <div class="page-header page-heading">
      <h1 class="pull-left">Forums</h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb pull-right where-am-i">
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li class="active">List of topics</li>
      </ol>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="lead">Welcome to the United Photographers Movement! Here  
you can post general or specific photography questions as well as 
locations to shoot. Finally, you can also post examples of your work 
for critique. <b>Note</b> Please check older posts before you post your 
own to make sure your question isn't already answered!</p>
    <table class="table forum table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="cell-stat"></th>
          <th>
            <h3>Questions</h3>
          </th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
          <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Frequently Asked Questions</a><br>
<small>General Questions</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 
542</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 
897</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Specific Questions</a><br><small>Questions 
about specific cameras or techniques for specific locations etc...
</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 
542</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 
897</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="table forum table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="cell-stat"></th>
          <th>
            <h3>Locations</h3>
          </th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
          <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
          <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Alabama</a><br><small>Search locations by 
state</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">6532</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">152123</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-magic fa-2x text-
primary"></i></td>
          <td>
            <h4><a href="#">Alaska</a><br><small>Search locations by 
state</small></h4>
          </td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">6532</a></td>
          <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a 
href="#">152123</a></td>
          <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">Jane Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 1 years ago</small></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="table forum table-striped">

      <table class="table forum table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="cell-stat"></th>
            <th>
              <h3>Critique</h3>
            </th>
            <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Topics</th>
            <th class="cell-stat text-center hidden-xs hidden-
sm">Posts</th>
            <th class="cell-stat-2x hidden-xs hidden-sm">Last Post</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x 
text-primary"></i></td>
            <td>
              <h4 class="theBigCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-
target=".collapse"><a href="#">Get your work critiqued</a><br>
<small>Please link your photographs <b>DO NOT</b> try to upload!
</small></h4>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">9 
542</a></td>
            <td class="text-center hidden-xs hidden-sm"><a href="#">89 
897</a></td>
            <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">by <a href="#">John Doe</a>
<br><small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 3 months ago</small></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>


        <div class="collapse">

          Testing
        </div>


      </table>




    </table>
  </div>
  </div>







  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="navbar-text pull-left">
        Site built by Self Aware Machines
      </p>

  <p>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-3 pull-right">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search  
Site"/>
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Search</button>
      </span>

    </div>
  </p>


$(document).ready(function(){
$(".theBigCollapse").click(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
});


.bigpappa{
  padding: 55px;
}

.forum.table > tbody > tr > td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.forum .fa {
    width: 1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.forum.table th.cell-stat {
    width: 6em;
}

.forum.table th.cell-stat-2x {
    width: 14em;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `#` selector on your `onclick` event which target an element with an id of `theBigCollapse`. Problem is on your html, that element you're using is a `class` and not an `id`.

So instead of doing `$("#theBigCollapse")` use this instead `$(".theBigCollapse")`

Also the reason why it brings you to the top is because of the anchor inside that element. 
`<a href="#">Get your work critiqued</a>`

To fix it, you need to prevent the default action when clicked. So to do that you need to add this also:

```
$(".theBigCollapse a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Your final JS should be like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".theBigCollapse").click(function() {
        $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
    });

    $(".theBigCollapse a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdoxsoo9/3/)

**Update**

Regarding the issue of having the "testing" appear above and not below is because you placed your `div` directly inside a `table` which is not valid.

e.g.

```
<table class="table forum table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>...
  <div class="collapse">
    Testing
  </div> 
</table>
```

To fix that, you can put your div inside `<td></td>` or even outside the `<table></table>`.

e.g.

```
<table class="table forum table-striped">
  <tr>
    <td>....</td>
  </tr>...
</table>

<div class="collapse">
  Testing
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdoxsoo9/6/)

P.S You have a table inside a table which I believe it's not necessary. I have fixed that on my fiddle.

You have this:

```
<table>
 <table>
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
 </table>
</table>
```

Comment: I love that it doesn't put me at the top of the page BUT it's still putting the content ABOVE the collapse

Comment: @MatthewSingleton Updated my answer. have a look.

Answer (score 1):

First change the content of  your JS file :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".theBigCollapse").click(function(){
    $(".collapse").collapse('toggle');
  });
});
```

This will make your text appear in below part (above the critique heading)

And to stop your page from going upwards everytime you click on critique heading, remove the data-target=".collapse" part from

```
<h4 class="theBigCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse">
```

There is no need of using data-target=".collapse" when you are triggering the collapse using bootstrap JavaScript functionality.

Comment: I love that it doesn't put me at the top of the page BUT it's still putting the content ABOVE the collapse